# What was the purpose of including (or rather excluding) Pittencream in the Voyage of the Dawn Treader?

Tags: c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia

In Chapter XIV of *The Voyage of the* Dawn Treader, Caspian and his friends have some difficulty in persuading all of the sailors on the *Dawn Treader* to continue beyond Ramandu's island to the end of the world. Some of them like Rynelf are very willing, but others feel that they've had enough. Caspian gives a speech to convince them that coming along would be an honour they should apply for rather than something they should be pressed into, after which the following happens:

> A good many who had been anxious enough to get out of the voyage felt quite differently about being left out of it. And of course whenever any one sailor announced that he had made up his mind to ask for permission to sail, the ones who hadn't said this felt that they were getting fewer and more uncomfortable. So that before the half-hour was nearly over several people were positively "sucking up" to Drinian and Rhince (at least that was what they called it at my school) to get a good report. And soon there were only three left who didn't want to go, and those three were trying very hard to persuade others to stay with them. And very shortly after that there was only one left. And in the end he began to be afraid of being left behind all on his own and changed his mind.
>
> At the end of the half-hour they all came trooping back to Aslan's Table and stood at one end while Drinian and Rhince went and sat down with Caspian and made their report; and Caspian accepted all the men but that one who had changed his mind at the last moment. His name was Pittencream and he stayed on the Island of the Star all the time the others were away looking for the World's End, and he very much wished he had gone with them. He wasn't the sort of man who could enjoy talking to Ramandu and Ramandu's daughter (nor they to him), and it rained a good deal, and though there was a wonderful feast on the Table every night, he didn't very much enjoy it. He said it gave him the creeps sitting there alone (and in the rain as likely as not) with those four Lords asleep at the end of the Table. And when the others returned he felt so out of things that he deserted on the voyage home at the Lone Islands, and went and lived in Calormen, where he told wonderful stories about his adventures at the End of the World, until at last he came to believe them himself. So you may say, in a sense, that he lived happily ever after. But he could never bear mice.

This curious tale adds a bit of (to me unexpected) colour to the story. I'm curious about **why this one man was excluded**, from both Watsonian and Doylist perspectives.

- Why did Caspian decide to exclude only one man, rather than taking everyone or excluding say the last three?
- What does this little mini-story contribute to the novel? Is there supposed to be a moral or an allegory here?